# Time format in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

In phonegap, is it possible to show the time in am/pm or 24-hour format according to the device settings in iOS? On the device, I can set the "24-Hour Time" to be on or off in settings. In the phonegap app, I want to adjust the time format according to the settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the phoneGap documentation and there doesn't appear to be a way to know what the device time format settings are.  But it's a good idea, you should submit a feature request to the Cordova (aka Phonegap) team for this feature.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

Now this isn't to say that a third party library doesn't exist that can work along side PhoneGap.  But you would have to hunt for a plugin that does that or write your own.  I did a quick Google search for this and nothing turned up for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll write a plugin then.

Comment: @subchap have u written a plugin for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cordova's built in [globalization plugin.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) If you run for example,

```
navigator.globalization.dateToString(
    new Date(),
    function (date) { alert('date: ' + date.value + '\n'); },
    function () { alert('Error getting dateString\n'); },
    { formatLength: 'short', selector: 'date and time' }
);
```

`date.value` will hold a dateString that will reveal the time format (just check if "AM" or "PM" is in the string).